# How to get in-app menus to work reliably in the GUI on Google Compute Engine?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm having trouble using dropdown menus in-app on Google Compute Engine after connecting through VNC. I have a working GUI in place, but more often than not, it doesn't allow me to use the dropdown menus in-app.

I need the GUI to setup configuration files for my headless crawler as doing that manually using the command line is too cumbersome (40ish parameters).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue relies directly on the VNC Client you are using. I would recommend you file a FR using this [Public Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187225&template=1162610) to fix this behavior in the GCP GUI Cloud Console.

Please include as much information as possible such as: VNC version and provider and so on.